# Semantic-UI Mixed Usage with Bootstrap/JQuery-UI

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, semantic-ui

I'm new to ui frameworks, and got into semantic UI as my first framework.
But after looking into JQuery UI and bootstrap, it has few things which Semantic UI doesn't have, 
such as carousels, which tempts me to spend the time to learn those frameworks as well.

So what I'd like to know is if there are many issues with mixed usage between Semantic-UI and the mentioned frameworks?
If there are, what type of issues are there?
Did anyone have any success with them?

Comment: Have you tried to use it? I'm interested to know that too.

Comment: @mike123
With semantic UI, I had success with JQuery UI Modal Dialog with Semantic UI Form (with difficulty), and JQuery Validations with Semantic UI Form (relatively easy).

Haven't dived too deep into JQuery UI, nor Bootstrap.

Comment: I could not use segments, messages and other things from SemanticUI inside jQuery UI Dialog. It simply doesn't match the rules.